# Contents of Genesis chapter 6

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit

What does the original Hebrew say about Genesis chapter 6, where in the Christian bible, angels came down from heaven and had children with man? Does the Torah say that this happened, and that it was angels?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. Do you want the Hebrew Masoretic text of [Genesis 6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0106.htm)?

Comment: what i am trying to understand is, in the Hebrew masoretic text: Genesis 6:2 what does "sons of God" refer to? (angels, men, other spiritual beings like jinn, the descends of Cane one christian text suggested). What i want to know is what the original Hebrew says they were?

Comment: very closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8858/what-does-the-term-sons-of-g-d-mean?rq=1

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, looks like a duplicate to me, no? John has clarified in the comment that he's seeking an explanation of "sons of God", which is precisely that question. I'm closing this; closure can be undone, of course, if warranted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jews don't always understand the simple meaning of any given verse of Torah - it always comes with thousands of years of commentary and tradition. The simple meaning of that sentence is unclear (the word "E-lohim" can mean "powerful ones," "angels" or "G-d"; "bnei E-lohim" means "sons of ...").

There's a debate about what exactly that word means in that case, but most commentators (Rashi, Ramban, Ibn Ezra) agree that it refers to "sons of judges" or the like. See http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.2 for several commentaries to that effect.